# Multiple divs on fluid row with two different spans

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get a space in between the div that has a span6 - either `margin-left:` or `margin-right:` having a margin of 20px spacing, the remaining space on the right I think is about 20px. Can anyone out there make my red divs have a space so that the layout looks fluid?

My layout will have span12 and span6 and the span6 must show two divs in a row.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/38rpB/1/)

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12">1</div>
        <div class="span6">2</div>
        <div class="span6">3</div>
        <div class="span12">4</div>
        <div class="span6">1</div>
        <div class="span6">2</div>
        <div class="span12">3</div>              
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the CSS I'm using:

```
.span12 {
    background-color:grey;
}
.span6 {
 background-color:red   
}
.row-fluid [class*="span"] {
margin-left:0px; margin-bottom:20px
}
.row-fluid .span6:nth-child(3n) {
   margin-left:20px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in bootstrap a row can contain only a maximum of 12 columns altogether in your case you have so many columns

it is not the number of columns it is the total of span counts like 12 + 6 + 6 etc

you need to split it into multiple rows

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12">
            1
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span6">
            2
        </div>
        <div class="span6">
            3
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12">
            4
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span6">
            1
        </div>
        <div class="span6">
            2
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12">
            3
        </div>              
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kuFXN/) - you need to expand the width of the result panel since responsive css is not included